# How can I print cPacket?

Tags: omnet++, inet

How do I print cPacket in inet 3.3.0 version ?

I think that the version don't have Printer function
I saw that in 4.0 version it has the Printer Packet Function, but I don't know if has some any function in 3.3.0 version for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper packet printing requires correct serialization/deserialization of packets and those APIs were introduced only in INET 4.x so the answer is no, there is no similar functionality in INET 3.x